# Use 12.04 Greybird's theme in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, themes, greybird

I would like to use the default theme (Greybird) from Xubuntu 12.04 in Xubuntu 14.04, simply because I believe the older version of Greybird is prettier.  I attempted to copy the contents of /usr/share/themes/greybird of my 12.04 installation and placed them on my 14.04 installation. However the theme did not load right. Is there a way to use the old Greybird theme from Xubuntu 12.04 on Xubuntu 14.04?

Comment: My recollection is that the themes themselves are flat files. You will have to review them in an editor and see what the difference is. You may have to re-write the theme to your liking, but should be able to use the themes you have as a template.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. This might help...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2083643

Comment: Descriptive answers are preferred over link-only ones, because if the link dies the answer becomes moot.